# For-loop value being updated

Tags: c#, function, for-loop, iteration

I have been practising C# by creating some code to find the factorial of a number.
The problem I have is how C# uses the for loop, and how it keeps the value in a recursive fashion.

Here is my code (Which uses iteration to achieve its goal):

```
static int Factorial_It(int fac)
        {

            int fac_test = fac;

            for (int i = 1; i <= (fac_test - 1); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i = " + i);
                Console.Write($"{i} * {fac} = ");
                fac = fac * i;
                Console.Write(fac + "\n");
            }
            return fac;
        }
```

I have had to assign a variable for the function's input (fac_test), then use that variable to start the loop as it stays the same throughout.

In a different programming language, I do no need to make this change as the original value inputted is used by the for-loop, and never changed as the loop goes on.

The code works fine with this change, but I would appreciate more knowledge on why C# syntax is like this - Is there a way the for loop doesn't update the value every "loop" ?

For reference, here is the code before I made the fix:

```
static int Factorial_It(int fac)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= (fac - 1); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i = " + i);
                Console.Write($"{i} * {fac} = ");
                fac = fac * i;
                Console.Write(fac + "\n");
            }
            return fac;
        }
```

As such, for value bigger than 3 or so, the for loop will keep going up until it hits a massive number, because the fac variable is constantly getting bigger (rather than staying the same as the original function input)

I hope my explanation is clear, and sorry for my poor english.

Forp

edit:

Here is the code I am basing this off of, in visual basic.

```
Function Factorial_It(Fac)
        For i = 1 To Fac - 1
            Fac = Fac * i
        Next i
        Return Fac
End Function
```

Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Yes, the condition is tested on each iteration, with the current values of the variables. That's the expected behaviour. Could you clarify what you're looking for in terms of an answer here? (Fundamentally, "the result" and "the number of times you want to iterate" are different pieces of information, so belong in different variables.)

Comment: Could you provide a name of a programming language where the original version works like you think it should? Every language I know would update the **fac** value, c# is not an exception here.

Comment: That is a very strange way to compute factorial, on the one hand you're saving an operation by not multiplying by `fac`, on the other you're wasting an operation by multiplying by `1`. Also your function returns `0! = 0`, which is wrong.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, he probably means Python and its list iterator thingie, which you can also do in C# with `Enumerable.Range`.

Comment: @Blindy: yeah, I meant a C-like languages of course with this specific loop syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to loop without the end value moving on you, you could always go backwards.

```
for (int i = fac - 1; i>0; i--)
{
    fac = fac * i;
}
```

This works because the initializing condition is executed only once at the beginning of the loop. The boundary check is done every time, and no, there is no way to change that behavior, other than using a separate variable.

Comment: that answers it. I too have done this backwards but was wondering why in this case (going forwards) it is different - It is clear that my syntax and understanding of the for loop was incorrect in this language. Specifically the words : The initializing condition is executed only once at the beginning of the loop. The boundary check is done every time" has been useful in my query, thanks. In context to my question the intializing condition would be fine, but the boundary check would be updated "every loop" and so I was having this issue.